# How to Compare Aspose Cells to Files in NetWork Folder

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, aspose, aspose-cells

I am new here and looking for some help, as I’ve been stuck on an issue…

I’ve been tasked with creating an app that requires me to compare a range of aspose cells in ** c#** to an iteration of file names. if they don’t match, then I have to add said files name that only exist in the network folder, into the excel sheet using aspose.

I am trying to compare a range of cells that comes from a workbook, to a list of file names that pulls from a network folder (the list is not in a workbook).

What I am trying to do is:

if network folder file name list (strings, not a workbook)
and
worksheet cells range values (a workbook)
do not contain all the same values,
then… add what is different in the network folder, to the worksheet

I am just wanting to know if it is possible to do it in the way I have been asked, and if so.. what is the best way to go about it?

I’m lost on how to go about this, as everything I’ve tried has told me I cannot use “Cells” like I am - with values of int and bool when it comes to conditional statements.

I’m new to both C# and Aspose.Cells… so thank you for your patience in helping me get this figured out :)

I have tried using if statements when trying to compare the cell range to the list from the network folder, but no variation of that seems to work. Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Code for network folder lists:

```
static void SSLSearch(string dir, string rootDir = null)
            {
                if (rootDir == null)
                {
                    rootDir = dir;
                }
                try
                {
                    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
                    {
                        if (f.Contains(".pfx"))
                        {
                            string filename = f.Substring(rootDir.Length);
                            Console.WriteLine(filename);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

Code for aspose range:

```
TxtLoadOptions txtLoadOptions = new TxtLoadOptions();
            txtLoadOptions.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            txtLoadOptions.ConvertNumericData = false;
            txtLoadOptions.ConvertDateTimeData = false;

            LoadOptions loadOptions = new LoadOptions(LoadFormat.Auto);
            loadOptions.LoadFilter.LoadDataFilterOptions = LoadDataFilterOptions.CellData;

            Workbook wb = new Workbook(fileName, loadOptions);

            //get all sheets in workbook
            WorksheetCollection collection = wb.Worksheets;

            //get worksheet from sheet name
            Worksheet worksheet = collection["certs"];

            //range of expirations
            Range expRn = worksheet.Cells.CreateRange("F2:F33");
            expRn.Name = "ExpireRange";

            //range of certificates
            Range certRn = worksheet.Cells.CreateRange("B2:B33");
            certRn.Name = "CertRange";

            //access ranges for both
            Range range = wb.Worksheets.GetRangeByName("ExpireRange");
            Range certRange = wb.Worksheets.GetRangeByName("CertRange");

            //iterate cells in range, print their names and values
            IEnumerator expE = range.GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator certE = certRange.GetEnumerator();

            while (certE.MoveNext() && expE.MoveNext())
            {
                Cell c = (Cell)expE.Current;
                Cell cert = (Cell)certE.Current;

                Console.WriteLine("Certificate" + ": " + cert.StringValue);
                Console.WriteLine("Expires" + ": " + c.StringValue);
....
```

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Comparing the lists? Adding the value to the Excel sheet? Something else? Post the code you've written and explain where the difficulty is. If you haven't written code, you haven't broken the problem down into small enough parts yet.

Comment: Answers to "is it possible?" generally fall into the dichotomy of "no, this technically makes no sense whatsoever" or "yes, with enough time and caffeine". This doesn't sound like an outright technical absurdity, so the answer is probably "yes, with..." but, as I pointed out above, your post is not focused on a small enough problem. An answer that covers the whole thing would essentially be writing the whole application for you, and that's not what we do here. Programming is composing solutions to smaller problems in order to solve larger problems.

Comment: Perhaps the first step is to figure out why you *"cannot use "Cells" like I am"*. What have you tried? Start by posting that code. Provide the error (compiler or exception), or expected vs. actual output if doesn't give an error. Failing that, we're in the dark as to how to help you.

Comment: @madreflection, i have edited it to include the code I am working with. what I need help with is how to compare the aspose cells to the file names im getting from the network folder

Comment: Don't think of them as "cells" anymore. Once you have the value, they're just strings. You have two sets of strings. What's the set operation that gives you what's missing between two sets? You're missing the trees for the forest (yes, that is intentionally the reverse of the common saying). Focus on the minute details; don't get lost in the big picture.

Comment: Finally, taking a step back... do you not have a senior engineer at this company that you can ask for help on this? If you were given a task beyond your Zone of Proximal Development, you should be receiving guidance from those who expect you to do the work. But you also need to ask them for help.

Comment: @madreflection, okay, so two sets of strings.. i believe then i would use .Except?  I apologize as I have just started using C# about a month ago, I'm not very familiar... Thank you for the reality check and reminder to look smaller. It is all new and I am lost so that is helpful and less overwhelming

Comment: I do, but they are busy with deployments, and im working as an intern. I am definitely out of my scope, but that is part of learning

Comment: You're still learning how to break larger problems down in to smaller ones. That doesn't always come naturally. When I'm mentoring, I carve out the time to talk through the process, and ask leading questions to help show how to reframe problems to be easier to break down. If I have a more pressing matter, I don't expect progress to be made in the meantime because, well, you don't have the tools you need yet. Between you, me, and SO, you deserve better from the senior engineers so that your internship results in real learning.

Comment: And yes, `.Except()`. Good job pulling that out once the problem was reframed.

Comment: @madreflection, it has definitely been a learning curve and yes as you said I am still learning how to look at problems properly as a developer. Good on you for taking the time to explain and help develop those skills for those you work with - as well as expectations on progress when not available. I am hoping after they become less busy that it will get better. Thank you for your patience and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be two approaches for your task, you may pick any of the following.

1. You may make use of some Excel formulas for comparison/matching task. For example, you may try [XLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929) and/or [MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) MS Excel’s formula(s). You may compare each individual string (which is coming from your custom method call for network folder list (names of the files)) to compare/match with the range of cells (e.g., you already have A2:A10 range/area in a worksheet). Both formulas (XLOOKUP and MATCH) are supported by Aspose.Cells’ formula calculation engine, so you may input the formula(s) into respective cell(s) to know which file names (from your custom list) are matching/not matching when comparing with your existing range in the worksheet. All you need to do is insert the file names (from your custom method call (network folder)) into some cell(s) and then apply formulas accordingly. You can calculate formula(s) via Workbook.CalculateFormula method and get the results/resultant values at runtime by Aspose.Cells APIs.
2. You can perform the string comparison/matching task using [Find/Search feature](https://docs.aspose.com/cells/net/find-or-search-data/). You can search using each data/string (from your file names list) in the specific range of cells/area where you have already pasted in the worksheet.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.